# SIMD - как сложить значения из 2ух вектором одного типа

Tags: c++, c, simd

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сложить значения из вектором одного и тоже типа, но сами значения, которых занимает разное кол-во байт в этих векторах.

Вот для примера:

```
int main()
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    int my_int_sequence[16] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };


    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[0]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[4]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[8]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) & my_int_sequence[12]);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------



    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    char my_char_mask[16] = { 1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 };

    __m128i my_char_mask_my_m128i = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) &my_char_mask[0]);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

То есть я имею массив значений int в массиве my_int_sequence - и так как все 16 значений int не поместятся в один вектор __m128i, я загружаю эти значения по 4 значения в 4-е вектора __m128i.

Так же я имею массив из 16 байт, который так же загрузил в вектор my_char_mask_my_m128i.

И вот теперь хочу каждому 4 байтовому значению векторов my_int_sequence_m128i_x - прибавить, как бы соответствующее однобайтовое значение из вектора my_char_mask_my_m128i.

Проблема очевидно в том, что мне нужно сложить, как бы разные размерности. Возможно ли такое ?

Возможно мне нужно каждый байт вектора my_char_mask_my_m128i - как то трансформировать в 4 байта ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я смотрю, вы уже частично нашли ответ: [Что делает эта SIMD инструкция?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406312/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0-simd-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Только я бы всё таки рекомендовал использовать тут `_mm_cvtepi8_epi32`, так как тут складываются знаковые `int` со знаковыми `char`.

Принцип прост: расширняем `char` до `int`, складываем их, сдвигаем маску на 4 байта вправо. И так 4 раза.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

void show_sequence(const char* pstrMsg, int* pSeq);
void show_mask(const char* pstrMsg, char* pMask);

int main()
{
    int my_int_sequence[16] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 };
    char my_char_mask[16] = { 1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 };
    
    show_sequence("Source sequence", my_int_sequence);
    show_mask(    "Characters mask", my_char_mask);
    
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[0]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[4]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_3 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[8]);
    __m128i my_int_sequence_m128i_4 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[12]);
    
    __m128i my_char_mask_my_m128i = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)my_char_mask);
    
    my_int_sequence_m128i_1 = _mm_add_epi32(my_int_sequence_m128i_1, _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(my_char_mask_my_m128i));
    
    my_char_mask_my_m128i = _mm_bsrli_si128(my_char_mask_my_m128i, 4);
    my_int_sequence_m128i_2 = _mm_add_epi32(my_int_sequence_m128i_2, _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(my_char_mask_my_m128i));
    
    my_char_mask_my_m128i = _mm_bsrli_si128(my_char_mask_my_m128i, 4);
    my_int_sequence_m128i_3 = _mm_add_epi32(my_int_sequence_m128i_3, _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(my_char_mask_my_m128i));
    
    my_char_mask_my_m128i = _mm_bsrli_si128(my_char_mask_my_m128i, 4);
    my_int_sequence_m128i_4 = _mm_add_epi32(my_int_sequence_m128i_4, _mm_cvtepi8_epi32(my_char_mask_my_m128i));
    
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[0], my_int_sequence_m128i_1);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[4], my_int_sequence_m128i_2);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[8], my_int_sequence_m128i_3);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)&my_int_sequence[12], my_int_sequence_m128i_4);
    
    show_sequence("Result sequence", my_int_sequence);
    return 0;
}


void show_sequence(const char* pstrMsg, int* pSeq)
{
    printf("%s: {", pstrMsg);
    for (char i=0; i<15; ++i)
        printf("%2d, ", pSeq[i]);
    printf("%2d}\n", pSeq[15]);
}

void show_mask(const char* pstrMsg, char* pMask)
{
    printf("%s: {", pstrMsg);
    for (char i=0; i<15; ++i)
        printf("%2d, ", (int)pMask[i]);
    printf("%2d}\n", (int)pMask[15]);
}
```

---

```
Source sequence: { 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
Characters mask: { 1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1}
Result sequence: { 1,  1,  3,  4,  4,  6,  6,  8,  9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14, 16}
```