# Что делает эта SIMD инструкция?

Tags: c++, c, simd

Извините, но я, что то не могу по описанию понять, что делает эта SIMD инструкция:https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#ig_expand=7350,4869,514,6791,5444,5393,5260,101,152,101,6929,7101,121,7350,7332,1941&text=_mm_cvtepu8_epi32

mm_cvtepu8_epi32:

> __m128i _mm_cvtepu8_epi32 (__m128i a)
>
> Zero extend packed unsigned 8-bit integers in a to packed 32-bit
> integers, and store the results in dst.
>
> Zero расширяет упакованные 8-битные целые числа без знака в a до
> упакованных 32-битных целых чисел и сохраняет результаты в dst .

То есть на вход она принимает вектор __m128i и отдает тот же __m128i вектор. Это как ?

Что значит расширяет упакованные 8-битные целые чисел до упакованных 32-битных целых ? Никак не могу сообразить.  __m128i 16 байт, как были - так на выходе и остались.

Comment: По Вашей ссылке есть псевдокод, который все расскрывает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну допустим:

```
a == 0x4D3C2B1A
```

Тогда, согласно псевдокоду из документации

```
FOR j := 0 to 3
    i := 32*j
    k := 8*j
    dst[i+31:i] := ZeroExtend32(a[k+7:k])
ENDFOR
```

получим `__m128i b = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(a)`:

```
b == 0x0000004D0000003C0000002B0000001A
```

Другими словами, этот интрин берёт младшие 4 байта исходного операнда и и возвращает вектор из этих байт, бесзнаково расширенных до int.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, как Вы поняли этот псевдо-код ? Что такое - j,ik. Что такое ZeroExtend32.

Comment: Хотя ZeroExtend32 - это видимо что то типа memset - который зануляет 32 бита с указанного какого то непонятно номера элемента.

Comment: @Optimus1 `i`, `j`, `k` - псевдопеременные. Тут как бы всё очевидно: цикл FOR для `j`, меняющейся от 0 до 3. Конструкция `dst[y:x]` означает биты с позиции `x` по позицию `y` операнда `dst`. Название псевдофункции `ZeroExtend32()` говорит само за себя - расширить что-то до 32 бит, дополнив расширяемые биты нулями.

Comment: @Optimus1 надо понимать, что это не код, а псевдокод. Т.е., описание на некотором формальном языке того, что и как делает инструкция. Этот псевдокод, если вникнуть, максимально прост и интуитивно понятен. Биты нумеруются начиная с нуля, справа налево, если что.